NSCollectionView type select
I have implemented type selection for my NSCollectionView implementation.
In my collection view subclass, I have added additional delegate methods:
protocol CollectionViewDelegate : NSCollectionViewDelegate {
    func collectionViewDelegateTypeSelect(_ text: String)
    func collectionViewDelegateResetTypeSelect()
}

class CollectionView : NSCollectionView {
    
    override func keyDown(with event: NSEvent) {
        if let del = delegate as? CollectionViewDelegate {
            if (event.characters?.rangeOfCharacter(from: CharacterSet.alphanumerics.inverted) == nil) || (event.characters == " ") {
                del.collectionViewDelegateTypeSelect(event.characters!)
                return
            }
            else {
                del.collectionViewDelegateResetTypeSelect()
            }
        }
        if (event.specialKey == NSEvent.SpecialKey.pageUp) {
            scroll(NSMakePoint(0, max(0, enclosingScrollView!.documentVisibleRect.minY - enclosingScrollView!.documentVisibleRect.height)))
        } else if (event.specialKey == NSEvent.SpecialKey.pageDown) {
            scroll(NSMakePoint(0, min(enclosingScrollView!.documentVisibleRect.maxY, enclosingScrollView!.documentVisibleRect.origin.y + enclosingScrollView!.documentVisibleRect.height)))
        } else if (event.specialKey == NSEvent.SpecialKey.home) {
            scroll(NSMakePoint(0, 0))
        } else if (event.specialKey == NSEvent.SpecialKey.end) {
            scroll(NSMakePoint(0, frame.height))
        } else {
            super.keyDown(with: event)
        }
    }
    
}

Then in my delegate, which is a subclass of NSArrayController, I process the type selection:
    var timer: Timer?
    var typeString: String = ""
    var typeCount: Int = 0
    func collectionViewDelegateTypeSelect(_ text: String) {
        typeCount = 0
        typeString.append(text)
        findItemClosestToString(typeString)
        guard let _ = timer, timer!.isValid else {
            timer = Timer(timeInterval: 0.1, repeats: true, block: {_ in 
                self.typeCount = self.typeCount + 1
                if self.typeCount > 10 {
                    self.typeCount = 0
                    self.typeString = ""
                    self.timer?.invalidate()
                }
            })
            RunLoop.main.add(timer!, forMode: RunLoop.Mode.default)
            return
        }
    }
    
    func collectionViewDelegateResetTypeSelect() {
        if collectionViewDelegateIsTypeSelecting() {
            timer?.invalidate()
            timer = nil
        }
    }
    
    func sortedItems() -> ([NSManagedObject], [String]) {
        guard let items = (arrangedObjects as? [MediaItem]) else { return ([], []) }
        let sorted = (items as NSArray).sortedArray(using: [alphabeticalSortDescriptor]) as! [MediaSeries]
        return (sorted, sorted.map { $0.title })
    }
    
    func findItemClosestToString(_ text: String) {
        let (items, strings) = sortedItems()
        guard items.count > 0 else { return }
        var lo = 0
        var hi = items.count - 1
        var mid = lo
        while lo <= hi {
            mid = (lo + hi)/2
            let c = text.caseInsensitiveCompare(strings[mid])
            if c == .orderedDescending {
                lo = mid + 1
            } else if c == .orderedAscending {
                hi = mid - 1
            } else {
                break
            }
        }
        if strings[mid].localizedLowercase.hasPrefix(text.localizedLowercase) == false, mid + 1 < strings.count, strings[mid + 1].localizedLowercase.hasPrefix(text.localizedLowercase) {
            mid = mid + 1
        }
        selectItem(items, mid: mid)
    }
    
    func selectItem(_ items: [NSManagedObject], mid: Int) {
        let index = (arrangedObjects as! [NSManagedObject]).firstIndex(of: items[mid])!
        let path = IndexPath(item: index, section: 0)
        mainCollection.deselectAll(nil)
        //mainCollection.reloadData() - This was left over debug
        mainCollection.selectItems(at: [path], scrollPosition: .top)
        collectionView(mainCollection, didSelectItemsAt: [path])
    }

This works pretty good, however, as the number of items the collection view displays grows (> 1000), it is possible to type faster than the type selection works, leaving the user to watch a few seconds of the UI catching up.
The selection functions are broken apart to make overriding individual parts easier in subclasses.
The question I have is how to best collate multiple NSEvents so that in the event a few Events are queued, only the character is added, so that the unnecessary mid-selections occur. About the only way I can think to do this is to add an additional timer that collects one or more events before running the main selection algorithm. Hence all that happens between user input, is the typeString grows in length without proceeding further to doing the selection until I'm reasonably sure no additional input will come in.
When I started working through that, I figured there had to be a better approach. I know that NSTableViews and NSOutlineViews support type selection out of the box, but NSCollectionViews do not appear to.
What I'm curious about is if there is a better approach that I've just completely missed. I haven't found anyone else attempting to add type selection to a NSCollectionView.
Edit: To clarify, this code works, but is slow with a large number of items in the collection view. I can make it faster by changing the way collectionViewDelegateTypeSelect() works to wait a few iterations of the timer to collect additional characters, so less selection events are done overall. However, this seemed a bit nasty and made me think there must be a better approach I was missing.
The delegate is a NSArrayController bound to the CollectionView. It is mutable, and can be sorted using multiple different user defined NSSortDescriptors. It is a mutable array and the user can add/remove items to the CollectionView.

Did you bind the collection view to the array controller? Are the items mutable? Is arrangedObjects sorted? Why do you call reloadData?

What does collectionViewDelegateIsTypeSelecting do?

Yes, as I said, this code works, it is just slow if there are a large number of items.

I removed that from the subset of code I showed for simplicity, but it is another delegate function that just returns whether the timer is present and valid. A subclass of CollectionView also allows the space bar to display a popup preview of the currently selected item in the collection view. It checks with the delegate to see if there is a current type selection in progress to interpret the space character as a character for type selection, or whether it should trigger the popup to display.

Off topic: Shouldn't sortedItems return (sorted, sorted.map { $0.title })?

The CollectionView is bound to an NSArrayController and is mutable, and the sorting of that array is user configurable, and may or may not be in alphabetical order, which is why I have to do a sorting to find the relevant matching type selection.

Yeah, that is an oversight. I'll make that change.

Have you tried scheduling the search? NSTableView schedules the reset and cancels it when a key is typed. Instead of timers you could use DispatchQueue and DispatchWorkItem.

I haven't. Never used them, so it didn't occur to me. From a bit of reading, sounds exactly what I was looking for. I'll give it a go and report back. Thanks.

Willeke's idea of using DispatchQueue worked well. There is some fine tuning I need to do to work out the best time to delay the future execution.
var clearTypeSelect: DispatchWorkItem?
var issueTypeSelect: DispatchWorkItem?
var typeString: String = ""
var typeSelect: Bool = false
override func collectionViewDelegateTypeSelect(_ text: String) {
    clearTypeSelect?.cancel()
    issueTypeSelect?.cancel()
    typeString.append(text)
    let clearWorkItem = DispatchWorkItem {
        self.typeString = ""
    }
    clearTypeSelect = clearWorkItem
    DispatchQueue.global().asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + .milliseconds(1000), execute: clearWorkItem)
    let selectWorkItem = DispatchWorkItem {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.findItemClosestToString(self.typeString)
        }
    }
    issueTypeSelect = selectWorkItem
    DispatchQueue.global().asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + .milliseconds(300), execute: selectWorkItem)
}

Thanks. There's a bit of clean up I still have to do, but I think this is the answer.
